# How do I get the sum of two json objects?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, reduce

This is the json data I have. I need the sum of 'homescorepoints' + 'homeframepointsadj' and/or
'awayscorepoints' + 'awayframepointsadj'...

```
"512830": {
    "compname": "VNEA Vegas League",
    "grade": "",
    "hometeamlabel": "Pool Tang Clan",
    "homeshortlabel": "Pool Tang Clan",
    "awayteamlabel": "All Shades",
    "awayshortlabel": "All Shades",
    "homescore": 11,
    "homescorepoints": "187",
    "homeframepointsadj": "5",
    "awayscore": 14,
    "awayscorepoints": "178",
    "awayframepointsadj": "0",
}
```

I understand the basic array. Reduce for adding multiple occurrences of say "awayscore", but I'm have a mental block with adding two separate objects values together.

Comment: What doesn't *adding two separate objects values together* means? There is only single object here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to sum values from this example object: .reduce() accept arrays so, you can use Object.values() method for your object to get the array and than use .reduce() like this:

```js
const jsonData = {
  "512830": {
    "compname": "VNEA Vegas League",
    "grade": "",
    "hometeamlabel": "Pool Tang Clan",
    "homeshortlabel": "Pool Tang Clan",
    "awayteamlabel": "All Shades",
    "awayshortlabel": "All Shades",
    "homescore": 11,
    "homescorepoints": "187",
    "homeframepointsadj": "5",
    "awayscore": 14,
    "awayscorepoints": "178",
    "awayframepointsadj": "0",
  }
};

const calculateScore = (data, type) => 
  Object.values(data).reduce((acc, curr) => 
    acc + parseInt(curr[`${type}scorepoints`]) + parseInt(curr[`${type}framepointsadj`]), 0);

const homeScore = calculateScore(jsonData, 'home');
const awayScore = calculateScore(jsonData, 'away');

console.log(homeScore);
console.log(awayScore);
```

Comment: +1, Thank you very much, Been awhile since I've worked with some of this stuff, I just couldn't picture the solution.

Much appreciated.